# can we go directly to a slide (suppose from 1 to 6) in iDanerous swiper rather then going through from 2-5 then 6

Tags: jquery, slider, swiper.js

I am using iDangerous swiper. Can we go directly to a slide an specific slide (suppose from 1 to 6) in iDanerous swiper rather then going through from 2-5 then 6.

Documentation says to use `slideToClickedSlide` this property in config but it doesn't work.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think you need a comma at the end of `slideToClickedSlide: true`, but I doubt that will help. Does anyone else know how to do this?